# Functor computing error vector and Jacobian in a single call using Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm using the Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt solver for a model fitting application. The functor I'm providing to it includes functions to compute the error vector and Jacobian. These functions contain a lot of similar code and some costly calculations are repeated duplicated.

The prototype of the () operator used to compute the error vector includes what appears to be an optional pointer to a Jacobian matrix. If the Eigen::LevenbergMarquardt solver can be setup to compute the error vector and Jacobian at the same time in relevant cases it would really speed up my algorithm.

```
int operator()(const Eigen::VectorXf& z, Eigen::VectorXf& fvec, Eigen::MatrixXf* _j = 0)
```

I have not found any documentation describing this `_j` parameter or how it can be used. Checking its value during my code shows it is always a NULL pointer.

Does anyone know what this parameter is used for and if it's possible to compute the error vector and Jacobian simultaneously when both are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this particular solver but these kind of parameters are commonly only used whenever the solver needs it. Maybe it is just an extension point for the future. Looking at the source code, the LM solver never calls the functor with that parameter.

I think a better approach in your case would be to cache redundant parts of the computation within your functor. Maybe just keep a copy of the input vector and do a quick memcmp before doing the computation. Not ideal but since the interface has no way of telling you when the inputs change, that's probably the most robust option you have.

Comment: Yeah that was the backup plan. Thanks for looking into this!